# Make specter return (part of) the selected path

Tags: clojure, specter

In the following structure, I know how to iterate over the `:x` values of all children of `:whatever`:

```
=> (specter/select
       [:whatever specter/MAP-VALS :x]
       {:whatever {:a {:x 1} :b {:x 2}}})
[1 2]
```

What I'd like to get though is something like the following, that contains the wild-carded map key.

```
[[:a 1] [:b 2]]
```

How can this be done with specter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(select
        [:whatever ALL (collect-one FIRST) LAST :x]
        {:whatever {:a {:x 1}
                    :b {:x 2}
                    :c {:x 55}}})
=> [[:a 1] [:b 2] [:c 55]]
```